# use sed on bash to keep a specific string in a line?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I have a file (/etc/passwd) with thousand of lines like:

```
nom de login:password:uid:gid:nom en clair:home dir:shell
```

I want to keep the 'nom en clair' field and delete the other parts using `sed 's/..etc..`

How can I do that please ?

I have done it in `vi` using this expression:

```
:%s#\%([^:]\+:\)\{4}\([^:]\+\).*#\1
```

Comment: did you want to do the replacements on all the lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
s='nom de login:password:uid:gid:nom en clair: home dir:shell'
awk -F: '{print $5}' <<< "$s"
nom en clair
```

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\([^:]*:\)\{4\}\([^:]*\).*$/\2/' <<< "$s"
nom en clair
```

Comment: Yes but default `sed` doesn't support non-capturing groups.

Comment: Sure I have provided `sed` command also. Just use `sed 's/^\([^:]*:\)\{4\}\([^:]*\).*$/\2/' /etc/passwd`

Comment: Yes sure it does have many more lines but I believe `nom en clair` (or any name) will be in 5th column always.

Comment: @user3568611 Use `sed '...' /etc/passwd` instead of `sed '...' <<< "$s"` to get ALL lines processed

Comment: î works thank you, I will just ask you last thing: explain me s/^\([^:]*:\)\{4\}\([^:]*\).*$/\2/' part by part because it's a little bit hard for me to understand.

Comment: Yes sure. `^([^:]*:)\{4\}` matches first 4 fields in passwd file separated by `:` and `([^:]*)` matches and captures 5th field in group #2 to be used in replacement pattern.